# Inputting a string to a local variable instead of a member variable

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

All of the code works to my liking yet, my Customer Name and Initial Balance are not being stored because when the functions are run it just inputs 0 as Initial Balance. Am I making a simple mistake?
main. cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char Redo;
    string CustomerName;

do
{
    float InitialBalance = -1;
    float balance1 = 0;
    float balance2 = 0;


    Account Account;
    Account.CreditAccount (balance1, InitialBalance);
    Account.DebitAccount (balance2, InitialBalance);
    Account.DisplayBalance (CustomerName, balance1, balance2);

    //Asks user if they want redo the program
    cout << "Would you like to redo the program?\n";
    cout << "Please enter Y or N: \n \n";
    cin >> Redo;
}while(Redo == 'Y' || Redo == 'y');


char exitchar; //Exit's the program.
cout << "\nPress any key and <enter> to exit the program.\n";
cin >> exitchar;

return 0;
}
```

Account.h

```
using namespace std;

class Account {
public:
    float balance1;
    float balance2;
    string CustomerName;
    float InitialBalance;
    float CreditAccount(float& balance1, float InitialBalance);
    float DebitAccount(float& balance2, float InitialBalance);
    float DisplayBalance(string CustomerName, float balance1, float balance2);
    Account (void);


    Account(float balance)
    {
        SetInitialBalance(balance);
    }
    void Account::SetInitialBalance(float balance)
    {
        if(balance >= 0)
        {
            InitialBalance = balance;
        }
        else
            cout << "Error! Initial Balance cannot be less than 0." << endl;
    }
};

Account::Account(void)
{
string CustomerName;

cout << "Your Account Machine" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your last name." << endl;
cin >> CustomerName;
while(InitialBalance < 0)
{
cout << "Please enter your account balance. No Commas." << endl;
cin >> InitialBalance;
if(InitialBalance < 0)
    cout << "Error account balance must be positive." << endl;
}
}

float Account::CreditAccount(float& balance1, float InitialBalance)
    {
        float CreditInput = -1;
        while(CreditInput<0){
        cout << "Would you like to credit the account? Enter the amount you would like to credit." << endl;
        cin >> CreditInput;
        if (CreditInput<0)
            cout << "Credit must be positive." << endl;
        }
        balance1 = (CreditInput + InitialBalance);
        return balance1;
    }
float Account::DebitAccount(float& balance2, float InitialBalance)
    {
        float DebitInput = 0;
        while((InitialBalance - DebitInput)<0){
        cout << "Would you like to debit the account? Enter the amount you would like to debit." << endl;
        cin >> DebitInput;
        if((InitialBalance-DebitInput)<0)
            cout << "You cannot debit more than you have avalaible." << endl;
        }
        balance2 = (InitialBalance - DebitInput);
        if( DebitInput > InitialBalance)
        {
        cout << "Debit amount exceeds account balance." << endl;
        return 0;
        }
        else 
            return balance2;
    }
float Account::DisplayBalance(string CustomerName, float balance1, float balance2)
    {
        cout << "Customer Name: " << CustomerName << endl;
        cout << "Account Balance for credited account: " << balance1 << endl;
        cout << "Account Balance for debited account: " << balance2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So all of your code works how you want it to, but you have a problem with it. Just pointing that out. Anyway, you need to cut this down to a minimal example and provide exact input and output.

Comment: @chris I meant the rest of my code does. If you input the Customer Name and Initial Balance its not storing it properly so that it is usable in the other functions.

Comment: You can make your code more readable by prefixing member variable names with "m_". It would then immediately become obvious that your problem is that you have a local variable and a member variable with the same name, causing your changes to be local to a function and not the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have declared a new the local variable `CustomerName`. You are taking input to it but not to the member variable.

```
Account::Account(void)
{
    string CustomerName; // This is different from the member variable
    .....
    cin >> CustomerName;  // You are taking input to the local variable
                          // but not to the member variable
```

Comment: how would I input it to the member variable?

Comment: remove the local variable or give them distinct names so you can specify the one you mean.

Comment: It still doesn't read the name correctly even if I remove the local variable. It still shows up as blank in DisplayBalance.

Comment: You are passing variable called `CustomerName` to the `Account::DisplayBalance` member function. So, again you are accessing the passed variable rather than member variable. To access the member variable, do `this->CustomerName`. ( I strongly suggest to append `m_` before all member variables to differentiate from others )

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you assume, the variables in the "main" function would change, if the Class members change.

```
int main()
{
    char Redo;
    string CustomerName;

    do
    {
      float InitialBalance = -1;
      float balance1 = 0;
      float balance2 = 0;

      Account Account;
      // [..]
      Account.DisplayBalance (CustomerName, balance1, balance2);
      // [...]
    }while(Redo == 'Y' || Redo == 'y');
}
```

But if you create a new `Account` and never set the real Account values, they wont ever be stored.

This whole program makes not much sense if you create local variables everywhere that you set to some value. One example:

```
Account::Account(void)
{
string CustomerName;

// [..]
cin >> CustomerName;
// [..]
}
```

this creates a local variable in the constructor function that is no real class member and stores the customers name into this local variable. the real class member "CustomerName" is never set and the local variable will be deleted after the constructorfunction is ready.

better do:

```
Account::Account(void)
{    
string cname;
// [..]
cin >> cname;
this->CustomerName = cname;
// [..]
}
```

I'm sorry if I did any faults :)

Comment: `this` is of type `const Account *`. So, you need to use `->` operator.

Comment: I got it! I really appreciate it.